# ASP.NET common controls source code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0

Is there a source code readily available for commonly used controls (say found in the toolbox) for ASP.NET 2.0?

The level of detail that I want its that I need to know the internal workings of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET QuickStart Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/whatsnew.aspx) best fit for your needs.

Here you can access : [Standart Toolbox Control Tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/default.aspx)

**EDIT :** You edited your post to get resource for inner workings of server components.
Here is my another suggestion : **Nikhil Kothari**'s [Developing Microsoft ASP.NET Server Controls and Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615829) is the best resource on components and inner workings.

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41AQGWDEYAL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41AQGWDEYAL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Microsoft has actually released the Source code for the System.Web assembly, amongst others.

It is intended to make it possible to debug the built-in classes, so you as a developer have a better chance of understanding why a specific class behaves as it does. You can make Visual Studio download the source on-the-fly, when you try to step-in to a function with the debugger.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx

If you would like to read / browse the source code; you can also download it all [using the NetMassDownloader project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/netmassdownloader.aspx) from CodePlex.

Comment: It is available, but not easily found. Try this: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to look at the source code of controls or any other class libraries is to use disassembler, for example .NET Reflector [link text](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Answer (score 0):

They are all documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com). Get started at the [ASP.NET Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/default.aspx), and at http://asp.net.